# css ::selection tag isn't working properly

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I want to use the `::selection` CSS tag on my website but every time I use it and try it live, there are some highlighted parts that keep behaving normally. That happens with spaces and some other stuff. Do you know why and how can I fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/o2bbog66/

Comment: Please post an example of the code you have the illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 9):

It's worth noting that `::selection` was [**removed** from the Selectors Level 3 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selection) and should logically be avoided until [Pseudo-Elements Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-pseudo-4/#selectordef-selection) is supported by modern browsers. For this reason, you may witness strange issues on browsers which did implement the Selectors Level 3 version of the pseudo-element.

> ### 7.3. Blank
>
> This section intentionally left blank. (This section previously defined a `::selection` pseudo-element.)

The [MDN article on `::selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) goes further by quoting:

> Though this pseudo-element was in drafts of CSS Selectors Level 3, it was removed during the Candidate Recommendation phase,  as it appeared that its behavior was under-specified, especially with nested elements, and interoperability wasn't achieved.

The problem you're having here is most likely caused by the same nested elements mentioned above.

Comment: The ::selection pseudo-element has been added again in Pseudo-Elements Level 4. Plus it still appears to work in various browsers http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wbkz05t0/

Comment: @j08691 I've updated my answer. It was removed due to it not being clear how it should affect nested elements - this sounds exactly like the issue that would be causing the problem mentioned in this question.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the OP's code (which for some reason he's left out of his question).

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, here you can have a look to the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/o2bbog66/

Comment: @FedericoFerrari yep. Nested elements. Removing the `br` elements and setting the `.where` elements to `display: inline` seems to fix it, but that obviously breaks your current style. As I said though, `::selection` should ideally be avoided if possible for the time being.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly thanks so much! Is there any other solution to keep the .where centered?

Comment: @j08691: I had no idea there was a Pseudo-Elements Level 4 module. But I guess it makes sense to separate them since pseudo-elements are a different concept from selectors altogether.

Comment: @j08691: Oh - the FPWD appeared just three weeks ago. No wonder.

Comment: The original definition of `::selection` can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-selectors-20051215/#UIfragments). As you can see, not much to go on. It's still extremely poorly defined in Pseudo-Elements 4 - it has simply been recategorised with no additional work done on it as yet.

Comment: @BoltClock - I didn't know about the  `::spelling-error` and `::grammar-error` pseudo elements myself.

Comment: @j08691: Probably because they're brand new. This is a FPWD after all. I remember when Selectors 4 first came out - seeing all the new stuff made me *giddy*.